# monaco editor - "[ts] Unterminated regular expression literal"

Tags: javascript, jsx, monaco-editor

TS compiler does not recognise jsx tags, and fails parsing them.

This only happens when I set the language to be 'typescript'
(and there is no built in language for 'typescriptReact' :(

[image]

How to configure monaco so it will accept jsx?

I tried:

`monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.setCompilerOptions(options)`

I went through all of the options but none seem to work. (especially the jsx: 'react' option.

`monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.setDiagnosticsOptions({})`

`{ noSyntaxValidation: true})`

works, but removes all validations from TS. :S

finally I made sure that the language is set to 'typescript':

`monaco.editor.createModel("const a = <div></div>", "typescript", undefined)`

(yes, I also tried the filepath)

Comment: Is the file extension `.ts`? You should use `.tsx`.

Comment: Are you sure it's set to treat the file as JSX?

Comment: yes, I set the language to be 'typescript', and the file path to be ```monaco.Uri.file('file.tsx')```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> tl;dr - yes, the file needs to be '**.tsx**'.

I had a single instance of *Editor Model*, with *undefined* filename.
The correct way to set filename is using `Uri.file(filepath)` as path,

 and these errors are gone for **.tsx** (but not for *.ts* files).

as a bonus, I get to keep *undo history*, as long as I reuse existing models.

so yay!